# How do i make each child objectController observe a change in its parent arrayController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a parent `resource` and a child `route`: `addresses` and `address`

A child `addressController` (a `modelController`) `observes` its parent `addressesController` (`arrayController`) attribute 'saveRequested'; it then runs its internal action of `this.model.save()` when the attribute changes to true.

In the `addresses` template, `addresses` `link-to` `address`, so only one `address` is active (in an `outlet` in `addresses`) at any one time. When the user triggers the parent `saveRequested=true;`, only the active `address` observes and perform the required action. Although I was not expecting this behaviour, it does make sense that only one of the child routes is active at one time.

My question is, how do I manage this scenario so that each child `address`, loaded into memory and stored in the parent `addresses` `arrayController`, all respond to the parent save request? Reason: the user makes all the edits he wants of each address and then is supposed to be able to click Save in addresses to then save/persist all the changes made to each address at once.

My only solution thus far is to iterate (`forEach`) through each `address` stored in the `content` of `addressController` and call the returned `addressModel.save()` directly. The `forEach` returns the record/model, not the `addressController` (`objectController`) as I was expecting but now I sort of realise why. It works but to me this feels like i'm going through the back door. Do I need each `address` to be in its own outlet so that all are active and can observe at the same time?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not quite understood your question. I, however, know each `itemController` has a property `parentController` pointing to its ArrayController. You can use this with an observer to know when the parent controller changed:

```
ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    parentControllerDidChange: function() {
        ...
    }.observes('parentController.saveRequested')

});
```

Does it help you?

UPDATE: See comments below about assigning the target objectController to the arrayController's itemController.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think it solves my issue. My `addresses` template is as thus: `{{#each address in addresses}}<li> {{#link-to "addressEdit" address}}{{address.addressSummary}}{{/link-to}}{{/each}}` Therefore the addressController (objectController) is only substantiated when the user clicks and transitions to each `address`. The arrayController - the parent AddressesController - only stores each record/model: the AddressModel; it does not (it seems) contain the objectController...Problem is that ember does so much of this routing and controller-ing behind-the-scenes that it is not clear.

Comment: ArrayControllers have the `itemController` property. Using it, you can iterate controllers (with the content setted to the underlying model) instead of models. You can even create each instance depending on the model, overriding the `lookupItemController` method. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html Hope it helps!

Comment: Got you. I found that my `addresses[Array]Controller` wasn't automatically assigning the `addressEdit[Object]Controller` as its `itemController`. So I added `itemController: 'addressEdit'` to the `arrayController` class. Then I could iterate through the containted objectControllers by `this.forEach()`. Thanks for your help!